# Loosing content of 2D vector when passing by reference

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, reference, 2d-vector

I am solving a problem, but I have run into an error which is odd.
In the eval function I recieve scores as a reference to a 2d vector.
For the first many calls to eval the content of scores is preserved. However at some point the content of a subvector (`vector<int>`) in scores is lost - the size() of the subvector is 0.
When I however change the code to recieve scores as a copy (new instance of the vector) I do not run into the problem but obviously the code will be way to slow. Like this:

```
...
int eval(vector<int>&team, vector<vector<int>> scores){
...
void rec(int idx, int d, vector<int>& team, vector<vector<int>> scores){
...
```

The problem occurs with the following test-data.

```
22 6 2000
0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1
0 9 0 0 0 0
6 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 10 0
0 6 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0
2 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 10
0 0 10 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 10 0 0
6 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0
0 5 0 0 0 0
0 6 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0
10 0 0 0 0 0
0 10 0 0 0 0
0 4 0 0 0 0
```

Here is all the code. I hope you can help med resolve this and provide som insight as to why this error might occur. Also this is my first post on stackoverflow (let me know if I could have improved the post in any way :)).

EDIT: I initially had scores be a global variable (without passing it as a reference) but this gave the exact same error.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int N, K, C;
vector<int> teams;
int eval(vector<int>&team, vector<vector<int>>& scores){
  int s = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < K; i++){
    int m = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < K; j++){
      cout << team[j] << scores[team[j]].size() << " " << i << endl;
      m = max(scores[team[j]][i], m);
    }
    s += m;
  }
  return s;
}
void rec(int idx, int d, vector<int>& team, vector<vector<int>>& scores){
  if(d == K){
    teams.push_back(eval(team, scores));
  }
  for(int i = idx; i < N; i++){
    team[d] = i;
    rec(i+1, d+1, team, scores);
  }
}
int main(){
  cin >> N >> K >> C;
  vector<vector<int>> scores = vector<vector<int>> (N, vector<int> (K, 0));
  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < K; j++){
      cin >> scores[i][j];
    }
  }
  //for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) cout << i << " "<< scores[i].size() << endl;
  vector<int> team (K);
  rec(0, 0, team, scores);
  sort(teams.rbegin(), teams.rend());
  cout << teams[C-1] << endl;
}
```

Comment: If you suppose only to read data from `scores` and pass by value is slow you should use const reference

Comment: @Slava. I tried that: ``const vector<vector<int>>& scores``, but it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: It may not, but would make your code cleaner and help to eliminate possible modification of the vector were it is not suppose to be modified. In your case though you most probably access data out of bounds. To check that replace access via `operator[]` with method `std::vector::at()` which validates bounds. Another possible reason is data corruption, but that would happen again by accessing data out of bounds so using `at()` should help.

Comment: @Slava It is indeed an out of bounds error :) But the out-of-bounds error occurs because all the data stored in the 2d vector suddenly doesn't exist - the size of the subarrays go from 6 to 0 even though I don't modify the content at any point.

Comment: Data does not suddenly disappear. That probably happens because you modify another vector out of bounds. So again validate your access.

Comment: @Slava Oh.. I see. That resolved it. I got out of bounds on the team vector in the rec function. I would have thought that an outofbounds on that vector would have given me a seg-fault, but apparently not (I assume because the scores vector was right beside the team vector in memory. Thanks a lot for the insight :)